# Spring Boot + PostgreSql Sequence not available

Tags: spring, postgresql, jpa

I am working in a project developed with Spring  Boot and PostgreSql as Database.

I have created a sequence `user_seq` in PostgreSql for my `user` table

```
CREATE SEQUENCE "USER_MGMT"."USER_SEQ"
    INCREMENT 1
    START 1000
    MINVALUE 1000
    MAXVALUE 99999999
    CACHE 1;

ALTER SEQUENCE "USER_MGMT"."USER_SEQ"
    OWNER TO postgres;
```

Here is my `user` Table

```
CREATE TABLE "USER_MGMT"."USER"
(
    "USER_ID" bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('"USER_MGMT"."USER_SEQ"'::regclass),
    "FIRST_NAME" character varying(30) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "LAST_NAME" character varying(50) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "EMAIL_ID" character varying(70) COLLATE pg_catalog."default" NOT NULL,
    "DESK_NUMBER" bigint,
    "MOBILE_NUMBER" bigint,
    "IS_ACTIVE" boolean NOT NULL DEFAULT true,
    "CREATED_BY" character varying(70) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "MODIFIED_BY" character varying(70) COLLATE pg_catalog."default",
    "DATE_CREATED" timestamp without time zone,
    "DATE_MODIFIED" timestamp without time zone,
    CONSTRAINT "USER_ID_PK" PRIMARY KEY ("USER_ID"),
    CONSTRAINT "EMAIL_ID_UK" UNIQUE ("EMAIL_ID"),
    CONSTRAINT "MOBILE_NUMBER_UK" UNIQUE ("MOBILE_NUMBER")
)
WITH (
    OIDS = FALSE
)
TABLESPACE pg_default;

ALTER TABLE "USER_MGMT"."USER"
    OWNER to postgres;
```

I am creating an JPA entity for this user table,

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "`USER`")
@ToString
@EqualsAndHashCode
public class User extends Auditable<String> {

    /**
     * 
     */
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 5351767213835401599L;

    @Id
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "USER_ID", sequenceName = "USER_SEQ", allocationSize = 1)
    //Tried this also but not works
    @SequenceGenerator(name = "USER_ID", sequenceName = "`USER_SEQ`", allocationSize = 1)
    @GeneratedValue(generator = "USER_ID", strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    @Column(name = "`USER_ID`")
    private Long userId;

    @Column(name = "`FIRST_NAME`")
    private String firstName;
```

While inserting data to this user table, I am getting error says `user_seq` is not available.

```
ERROR: relation "USER_MGMT.user_seq" does not exist
```

It tooks as lower case even though I mentioned in Upper case in entity.This is must for upper case for all the tables and sequences. Is there anything I missed in entity?

Comment: i use `@identity` with Postgres, and it just works. Also please use plural table names, so you don't have to quote identifiers. Also, I'd let JPA create your table definitions for you...

Comment: @NeilMcGuigan, thank you for your suggestion, can you pls provide a simple sample of the same, I am very new to this all.